# How can I get the name of the current subroutine in Perl?

Tags: perl

In Perl we can get the name of the current package and current line number Using the predefined variables like `__PACKAGE__` and `__LINE__`.

Like this I want to get the name of the current subroutine:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print __PACKAGE__;
sub test()
{
    print __LINE__;
}
&test();
```

In the above code I want to get the name of the subroutine inside the function `test`.

Comment: What output do you want if the current subroutine is anonymous?

Comment: `sub test() {}` defines a function with a prototype of "()". I guess you wanted `sub test {}`

Comment: Also, don't put an ampersand (`&`) before you subroutine calls because it probably doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8087321/4632019) answer

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[caller](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/caller.html) is the right way to do at [@eugene pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559792/perl-getting-the-name-of-the-current-subroutine/2559821#2559821) if you want to do this inside the subroutine.

If you want another piece of your program to be able to identify the package and name information for a coderef, use [Sub::Identify](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Sub::Identify).

Incidentally, looking at

```
sub test()
{
    print __LINE__;
}
&test();
```

there are a few important points to mention: First, don't use [prototypes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes) unless you are trying to mimic builtins. Second, don't use `&` when [invoking a subroutine](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#DESCRIPTION) unless you specifically need the effects it provides.

Therefore, that snippet is better written as:

```
sub test
{
    print __LINE__;
}
test();
```

Comment: Most of this "answer" is not related to the question.

Answer (score 64):

Use the [`caller()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/caller.html) function:

`my $sub_name = (caller(0))[3];`

This will give you the name of the current subroutine, including its package (e.g. `'main::test'`). Closures return names like `'main::__ANON__'`and in eval it will be `'(eval)'`.

Comment: which gives you main::__ANON__ for an anonymous sub (or foo::__ANON__ if the anonymous sub is defined in package 'foo')

Comment: @mirod: `local *__ANON__ = "foo";` -- this can be used to set some name for anonymous subroutines.

Comment: with `local` approach some debug modules still not understand the given name. With this approach the do. see [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=395912)

Comment: A good question is why 25 years after gcc-2.95 had `__FUNCTION__` Perl still does not. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

I was just looking for an answer to this question as well, I found caller as well, but I was not interested in the fully qualified path, simply the literal current package name of the sub, so I used:

`my $current_sub = (split(/::/,(caller(0))[3]))[-1];`

Seems to work perfectly, just adding it in for if anyone else trips over this questions :)

Answer (score 3):

There special [`__SUB__`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/__SUB__.html) exists from `perl-5.16`.

```
use v5.16;
use Sub::Identify qw/sub_fullname/;
sub foo {
    print sub_fullname( __SUB__ );  # main::foo
}

foo();
```

Actually you can pass to `sub_fullname` any subroutine reference (even anonymous):

```
use Sub::Identify qw/sub_fullname/;
sub foo {
    print sub_fullname( \&foo );  # main::foo
    print sub_fullname( sub{} );  # main::__ANON__
}

foo();
```

Comment: And if someone want to give the name to `__ANON__` see [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=395912)

Comment: Unfortunately it seems Sub::Identify is not part of the Perl core distribution (as of 5.18.2).

Comment: The module Sub::Util is in Perl core since Perl 5.22. Sub::Util::subname() does the same thing as Sub::Identify::sub_fullname().