# unable to find the function definition in a perl codebase

Tags: perl

I am rummaging through 7900+ lines of perl code. I needed to change a few things and things were going quite well even though i am just 36 hours into perl. I learned the basic constructs of the language and was able to get small things done. But then suddenly I have found a function call which does not have any definition anywhere. I grep'ed several times to check for all 'sub'. I could not find the functions definition. What am I missing ? Where is the definition of this function. I am quite sure this is a user defined function and not a library function(from its name i guessed this).
Please help me find this function's definition.

Here is a few lines from around the function usage.

```
(cfg_machine_isActive($ep)) {
         staf_var_set($ep, VAR_PHASE, PHASE_PREP);
         staf_var_set($ep, VAR_PREP,  STATE_RUNNING);
      } else {
         cfg_machine_set_state($ep, STATE_FAILED);
      }
   }
   $rc = rvt_deploy_library();       #this is the function that is the problem 
   dump_states() unless ($rc != 0);
```

***Here is the answer:***

(i could not post this an answer itself cos i dont have enough reputation)

I found that the fastest way to find the definition of an imported function in perl are the following commands:

```
>perl.exe -d <filename>.pl
```

This starts the debugger.
Then; do

```
b <name of the function/subroutine who's definition you are looking for>
```

in our case that would mean entering:

```
b rvt_deploy_library
```

next press 'c' to jump to the mentioned function/subroutine.

This brings the debugger to the required function. Now, you can see the line no. and location of the function/subroutine on the console.

```
main::rvt_deploy_library(D:/CAT/rvt/lib/rvt.pm:60):
```

Comment: Please add some more context, something like a grep with context of 10 lines around the mysterious fonction usage.

Comment: @RC I have updated the question as you suggested

Comment: I would grep the code base for the function name.

Comment: I know that sir, and that didnt work ! i wasnt able to find it ! infact, I even looked for all occurrences of 'rvt' and 'deploy' and 'library' separately .. still nothing. Now I am fairly convinced that the function is not defined there .. i am looking for ways a programmer can do that .. I mean how she can sorta 'hide' the definition ..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the name of the current subroutine in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559792/how-can-i-get-the-name-of-the-current-subroutine-in-perl)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a number of ways to declare a method in Perl. Here is an almost certainly incomplete list:

1. The standard way, eg. `sub NAME { ... }`
2. Using MooseX::Method::Signatures, `method NAME (...) {...}`
3. Assignment to a typeglob, eg. `*NAME = sub {...};`

In addition, if the package declares an `AUTOLOAD` function, then there may be no explicit definition of the method. See [perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Autoloading) for more information.

Comment: you see there are other functions defined in the same code base .. and they all use sub. also I wanted to ask you, now that i have updated the question with some code, do you have any further ideas ?

Comment: check for AUTOLOAD methods in all of the modules that are imported by that file.

Comment: and how to check/find_out for all the modules that are imported by that file ? are there import statements in perl ?

Comment: Search for lines in the form `use XXX;` and `require XXX;`

Comment: Oh yes sir .. i am using that already .. and I am also using the -w (switch) and the -d (debugger) command options to solve my problem.

Answer (score 7):

You can inspect any perl value with the [B](http://perldoc.perl.org/B.html) module.  In this case:

```
sub function_to_find {}

sub find_sub (\&) {
    my $code = shift;
    require B;
    my $obj = B::svref_2object($code);  # create a B::CV object from $code

    print "$code:\n";

    print "  $$_[0]: $$_[1]\n" for
        [file    => $obj->FILE],
        [line    => $obj->GV->LINE],
        [name    => $obj->GV->NAME],
        [package => $obj->STASH->NAME];
}

find_sub &function_to_find;
```

which prints something like:

```
CODE(0x80ff50):
  file: so.pl
  line: 7
  name: function_to_find
  package: main
```

Answer (score 6):

[B::Xref](http://perldoc.perl.org/B/Xref.html) will show all functions declared in all the files used by your code.

Comment: Didn't know about B::Xref - nice!