# How to display the number of subroutines and their names in a perl script at the time of its execution?

Tags: regex, linux, perl

Consider the following Perl script **script.pl** as an example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
sub f1
{statements}
sub f2
{statements}
sub f3
{statements}
f1();f2();f3();
```

When I execute the script, it should show the following output:

**./script.pl**

> number of subroutines:3
>   names of subroutines:f1 f2 f3

When the code is executed, how can I count the number of subroutines, get their names, and then print them during runtime?

Comment: Are you asking what to insert instead of `statements`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the name of the current subroutine in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559792/how-can-i-get-the-name-of-the-current-subroutine-in-perl)

Comment: How is the question unclear? Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for [Devel::Symdump](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Symdump):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

{
    require Devel::Symdump;
    my $sym = Devel::Symdump->new('main');
    my @subs = $sym->functions;
    printf "Number of subroutines: %d\n", scalar @subs;
    printf "Names of subroutines: %s\n", join(q{, } => map { s/^main:://; $_ } @subs);
}

sub f1 {
    # statements
}

sub f2 {
    # statements
}

sub f3 {
    # statements
}

f1();
f2();
f3();
```

Output:

```
Number of subroutines: 3
Names of subroutines: f2, f1, f3
```

Answer (score 6):

[Devel::Examine::Subs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Examine::Subs) can do these types of things.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Devel::Examine::Subs;

my $des = Devel::Examine::Subs->new(file => $0);

my $subs = $des->objects;

say "number of subs:" . @$subs . "\n";

for my $sub (@$subs){
    say "name:  " . $sub->name;       # name of sub
    say "start: " . $sub->start;      # first line number of sub in file
    say "end: "   . $sub->end;        # last line number of sub in file
    say "lines: " . $sub->line_count; # number of lines in sub
    # $sub->code;                     # entire sub code from file
    # $sub->lines;                    # lines that match search term
    say "\n";
}

sub func1 {}
sub func2 {}
sub func3 {}
```

Output:

```
number of subs:3

name:  func3
start: 25
end: 25
lines: 1


name:  func2
start: 24
end: 24
lines: 1


name:  func1
start: 23
end: 23
lines: 1
```

Comment: It uses PPI to parse a file instead of examining the symbol table. That may be what one wants, but the distinction is not immaterial which is why we need clarification from the OP. Also, you do not need semicolons after subroutine bodies.

Answer (score 2):

I think the function you're looking for is [`caller`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/caller.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub test {

   my (
      $package, $filename,  $line,     $subroutine,
      $hasargs, $wantarray, $evaltext, $is_require,
      $hints,   $bitmask,   $hinthash
     )
     = caller(0);
   print "$subroutine called at $line of $filename\n";
}

test;
```

Note - without arguments, `caller` returns just package, filename and line. The number is a number of stack frames, in case you're nesting the subroutine.

Comment: `caller` just examines the current subroutine (or the call path/tree that led to the current subroutine. I think the OP wants information about all subroutines in a file, even if they are unrelated.